# Flutter Dart layouts, Stack, Positioned how to stretch matrix of Material Buttons over whole screen

Tags: flutter, dart, button, stack, flutter-positioned

How can I have matrix of material buttons stretch across whole screen, if I just use height they will stretch to little or out of the screen based on screen size?

I can do that easily just in matrix with height: double.infinity, and CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,.

Though when I add Stack and Positioned widgets to the mix, then screen goes white if I use height: double.infinity,. and I get error: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
MaterialButton file:///Users/janiveble/AndroidStudioProjects/midi_app/lib/main.dart:113:14

Though when I search for this error, I can't figure out how is it related to my issue.

Also how can I position text on white keys to the botom of key instead of center?

Also I would like to get width of white keys, as I would like to use it to control position and width of black keys based on it.

```
  Expanded buildWhiteKey({Color color, int soundNumber}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        //height: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        color: color,
        textColor: Colors.red,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        onPressed: () {
          //playSound(soundNumber);
          FlutterMidi.playMidiNote(midi: soundNumber);
          setState(() {
            userAnswer = soundNumber;
          });
        },
        child: Text('$soundNumber'),
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded buildBlackKey({Color color, int soundNumber}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        //height: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        color: color,
        textColor: Colors.red,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        onPressed: () {
          //playSound(soundNumber);
          FlutterMidi.playMidiNote(midi: soundNumber);
          setState(() {
            userAnswer = soundNumber;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          '$soundNumber',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  quizKey(color: Colors.green),
                  checkAnswer(color: Colors.red),
                ],
              ),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 96),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 98),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 100),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 101),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 103),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 105),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 107),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 97),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 99),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 102),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 104),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 106),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 84),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 86),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 88),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 89),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 91),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 93),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 95),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 85),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 87),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 90),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 92),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 94),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 72),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 74),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 76),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 77),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 79),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 81),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 83),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 73),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 75),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 78),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 80),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 82),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 60),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 62),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 64),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 65),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 67),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 69),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 71),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 61),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 63),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 66),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 68),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 70),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 48),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 50),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 52),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 53),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 55),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 57),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 59),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 49),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 51),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 54),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 56),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 58),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 36),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 38),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 40),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 41),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 43),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 45),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 47),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 37),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 39),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 42),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 44),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 46),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 24),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 26),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 28),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 29),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 31),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 33),
                  buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 35),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 25),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 27),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 30),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 32),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 34),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solved the issues

for proper button arrangements I've had to wrap Stack and Positioned widgets in one Expanded widget in proper place

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              quizKey(color: Colors.green),
              checkAnswer(color: Colors.red),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Row(children: <Widget>[
                buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 96),
                buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 98),
                buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 100),
                buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 101),
                buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 103),
                buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 105),
                buildWhiteKey(color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 107),
              ]),
              Positioned(
                  left: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  bottom: kbottomHeight,
                  top: 0.0,
                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Container(width: kkeyWidth),
                    buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 97),
                    Container(width: kkeyWidth * 0.5),
                    buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 99),
                    Container(width: kkeyWidth * 2),
                    buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 102),
                    Container(width: kkeyWidth * 0.5),
                    buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 104),
                    Container(width: kkeyWidth * 0.5),
                    buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 106),
                    Container(width: kkeyWidth),
                  ])),
            ]),
          ),
         
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
```

For proper aligment of text in Button widget I've used InkWell button widget and then it works fine.

```
  Expanded buildWhiteKey({Color color, int soundNumber}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            //playSound(soundNumber);
          },
          child: Container(
            //height: double.infinity,
            color: color,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Text(
                '$soundNumber',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

For how to get width of white keys, I'm not really sure how that works yet, but have work around, where I found how to control it with one constant and divide it or multiply based on position of black key.

Thank Ammar for your time and effort, even though your code didn't really work out for me (guess you couldn't really test it out as you didn't have machine at hand), though your advices helped me as well in my work.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using the full screen and you have fixed number of buttons, you may get the screen height and width using the below:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width //for screen width
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height //for screen height
```

then make your calculations based on it (eg. you have 7 by 7 buttons and a header so we can count them as 8 by 7 hence you can then create the height as MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/8, and the width as MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/7

for the text alignment within your keys you can use Align widget and put alignment: alignment.bottomCenter
I modified your code and I believe it should work as expected (not tested as I don't have testing device right now).

I have added height parameter to your white button builder and passed it on the build widget, and I wrapped your text widget with Align widget to position the text on the bottom, and created a variable for screen width and height. below is the modified code.

```
    Expanded buildWhiteKey({double height,Color color, int soundNumber}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        //height: double.infinity,
        height: height,
        color: color,
        textColor: Colors.red,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        onPressed: () {
          //playSound(soundNumber);
          FlutterMidi.playMidiNote(midi: soundNumber);
          setState(() {
            userAnswer = soundNumber;
          });
        },
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child:Text('$soundNumber')),
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded buildBlackKey({Color color, int soundNumber}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        //height: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        color: color,
        textColor: Colors.red,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        onPressed: () {
          //playSound(soundNumber);
          FlutterMidi.playMidiNote(midi: soundNumber);
          setState(() {
            userAnswer = soundNumber;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          '$soundNumber',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var whiteKeyWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/7; //this is the width of white key
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: screenHeight/8,
                child:Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  quizKey(color: Colors.green),
                  checkAnswer(color: Colors.red),
                ],
              )),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 96),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 98),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 100),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 101),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 103),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 105),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 107),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 97),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 99),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 102),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 104),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 106),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 84),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 86),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 88),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 89),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 91),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 93),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 95),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 85),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 87),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 90),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 92),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 94),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 72),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 74),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 76),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 77),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 79),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 81),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 83),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 73),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 75),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 78),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 80),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 82),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 60),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 62),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 64),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 65),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 67),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 69),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 71),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 61),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 63),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 66),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 68),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 70),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 48),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 50),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 52),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 53),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 55),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 57),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 59),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 49),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 51),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 54),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 56),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 58),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 36),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 38),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 40),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 41),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 43),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 45),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 47),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 37),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 39),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 42),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 44),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 46),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 24),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 26),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 28),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 29),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 31),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 33),
                  buildWhiteKey(height: screenHeight/8,color: Colors.white, soundNumber: 35),
                ]),
                Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 50.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 25),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 27),
                          Container(width: keyWidth2),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 30),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 32),
                          Container(width: keyWidth1),
                          buildBlackKey(color: Colors.black, soundNumber: 34),
                          Container(width: keyWidth),
                        ])),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, though it is not working.

Container(
        height: screenHeight/8,
        child:Row(
        children: <Widget>[
        quizKey(color: Colors.green),
    checkAnswer(color: Colors.red),
Container causes issue
error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 7 found. (extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named at [midi_app] lib/main.dart:468)

Comment: this error was caused because I forgot to close the additional container wrapping the Row on the top, however I corrected it on the answer.

Comment: getting issue with
MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MyApp file:///Users/janiveble/AndroidStudioProjects/midi_app/lib/main.dart:27:17

already tried to use MediaQuery but didn't figure out how to go about it

Comment: Also I've tried your code for aligning text on white keys, though nothing happens.

Tried similar approach already as well, though it seems it cannot be changed? or needs some special code for it

Comment: seems that you're using MyApp widget as your home page, that will cause the issue you just mentioned. to avoid this you should create another widget as your home, and keep MyApp to return MaterialApp widget with home: YourNewHomeWidget(); my answer assuming that you have some flutter knowledge and proper app structure. please share your full code to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes you are right, I've used this structure from gitHub open source package.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to share code otherwise, as it is to long, so I've shared it in a new answer to this original post